# .htaccess - detect /amp/ at end of URL and rewrite rule to a html file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Please help to achieve the following in .htaccess file

### Request URL

htpps://www.examplesite.com/folder/file/amp/

### Required conditions to check

1. Check if /amp/ is present at end of the URL [AND]
2. Check if /mobile/folder/file.html file is present

### Rewrite Rule

Rewrite to htpps://www.examplesite.com/mobile/folder/file.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the following would help :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^(.+)/amp/$"
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mobile/$1.html"  -f
RewriteRule "^(.+)/amp/$" "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mobile/$1.html"  [L]
```